# Implement interface using derived types of the types defined in the interface - why can't you do it?

Tags: c#

I have these interfaces:

```
public interface IService
{
    public interface IRequest { }

    void Do(IRequest request);  
}
```

Why is this implementation incorrect?

```
public class Service : IService  //Error: CS0535
{
    public class Request : IService.IRequest { }

    public void Do(Request request) { }
}
```

Comment: `Request` is _too specific_ - not all `IRequest`'s are `Request`'s

Comment: What if someone did `class SomeOtherRequest : IRequest{ }` then `IService service = new Service(); service.Do(new SomeOtherRequest())`? They're allowed to do that because the signature of `IService.Do` lets them, and `service` is an `IService`, but then the `Service.Do` method would receive a `SomeOtherRequest` rather than a `Request`, which would be bad

Comment: You may want something like `IService<TRequest> where TRequest : IRequest` instead.

Comment: @canton7 When using the Service instance, as in your example, the Do method would accept only Request types or types derived from Request as parameters. SomeOtherRequest would not be a derivative of Request, so your case would not work primarily for this reason.

Comment: @JeroenMostert your solution is better, although I would add the class constraint to TRequest. But this does not explain the reason for the error

Comment: @jangix In my example, `service` is an `IService` though. What if I passed `service` to a method which accepted an `IService` parameter? That method would think that it can call `IService.Do(IRequest)` with *any* `IRequest`, and there's nothing to tell it any different

Comment: @cantone7 Now I understand your example better, thank you. I think that in your example it is still correct to think that you can call IService.Do(IRequest) with any IRequest, precisely for the reason of existence of the interfaces, perhaps I am wrong, but according to my point of view when you specify as a type an interface instead of a concrete type you do it to keep yourself decoupled from a specific implementation. So this kind of case: IService.Do(IRequest), means DO without caring how you do it...  What do you think?

Comment: @jangix I failed to parse your message and I've no idea what you're asking I'm afraid

Comment: @cantone7 In the case described by you, why couldn't the method that takes the IService type as a parameter execute the Do method with any IRequest? Maybe that would be what the programmer wants. The meaning of the expression IService.Do (IRequest) should express precisely this freedom in input.

Comment: @jangix I don't follow. The point is that your `Service` class's `Do` method **only** accepts `Request` objects. But as we've shown, because `Service` implements `IService`, and `IService` has a `Do(IRequest)` method, callers can call `Do` and pass in **any** `IRequest`, not just `Request`. That's a problem. What if `Service.Do` accesses some property which only exists on `Request` but not `IRequest`? Bad things would happen if you were actually able to pass in something which wasn't a `Request`

Comment: @canton7 So the implementation of the Do method in the Service class can have as a parameter only an interface type (IRequest or derived interface), and not a derived class type (as is presumable). This should be the error described by the compiler.

Comment: @jangix It **is** the error you got. The error is "error CS0535: 'Service' does not implement interface member 'IService.Do(IService.IRequest)'". That's telling you that `Service` does not implement the `Do(IRequest)` method from `IService`. `Service` is allowed to define any other methods it wants, including an extra `Do(Request)` method if that's what you want to do -- the rule is just that it has to define `Do(IRequest)`, because that method is specified by `IService`. That is exactly what the compiler error tells you

Comment: @canton7 I think I understood what I was wrong with...
Defining the signature of a method in an interface has a different meaning from the same signature defined in a class.
Let me explain. In the class, the types associated with the parameters must match or be derived types from the instance types that the method callers will pass.
In the interfaces, the types of method parameters (but also properties and other members) must match exactly in the implementation of the interface in the class, so in the implementation you cannot specify derived types at the types defined in the interface. Ok?

Comment: @jangix Not really. There are two different things going on: *calling a method* and *implementing a method defined on an interface*. When you call a method (whether that method is defined on a class or on an interface), you can pass subtypes if you want. When you implement a method defined on an interface, you have to match the interface exactly (almost -- C# 9 lets the method return a more derived type, because that's safe). They're two different things. One is when you call a method from some code, one is when you implement an interface in a class

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's not possible implement an interface by specifying derived types instead of the types that the interface defines.
Otherwise, a restriction not foreseen by the original meaning of the interface would be imposed.

*All types defined in the interface must match exactly in their implementations* (C#9 allows methods to return a more derived type, because that's safe).

Thanks to @canton7, @Tholdrim and @Mathias R. Jessen, for helping me come to this conclusion.

Comment: The least you could do is upvote Tholdrim's answer: they put a lot of effort into very clearly explaining the issue. IMO it should be accepted too

Comment: @canton7 I have already voted for Tholdrim's answer and I have also thanked those who helped me. The answer I needed is the one that I myself summarized and added. Those who want to delve into the topic can see the demonstrations in Tholdrim's answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is because the interface requires a method with the signature `Do(IRequest request)` and you provide `Do(Request request)` in your implementation instead.

I think this will become clearer when we expand your example with the following code:

```
public class Request2 : IService.IRequest { }
```

And then we will try to perform the following:

```
var service = new Service();
var request = new Service.Request();
var request2 = new Request2();

service.Do(request); // OK
service.Do(request2); // Nope
```

Compare it with that:

```
IService service = AnyKindOfServiceResolver.Resolve<IService>();
var request = new Service.Request();
var request2 = new Request2();

service.Do(request); // OK
service.Do(request2); // OK
```

This difference is what makes your code unable to compile successfully. It also shows what is **required** of each class that is an implementation of the `IService` interface.

**Edit:** Looking at the comments section under your question, I can see that your concerns originate from a misunderstanding of the meaning of a nested interface. Think about your code like this:

```
public interface IService
{
    void Do(IRequest request);  
}

public interface IRequest { }
```

Placing the definition of `IRequest` inside the body of `IService` does not "bind" the two to each other in any way other than inheritance of visibility (`public` in this case).

**Edit 2:** This is how you can achieve what you are trying to do:

```
public interface IService<TRequest> where TRequest : IRequest
{
    void Do(TRequest request);
}

public interface IRequest { }

public class Service1 : IService<Request1>
{
    public void Do(Request1 request) { }
}

public class Request1 : IRequest { }
```

Or if you really insist on having nested types (`readability--` and `complexity++`):

```
public interface IService<TRequest> where TRequest : IService<TRequest>.IRequest
{
    public interface IRequest { }

    void Do(TRequest request);
}

public class Service : IService<Service.Request>
{
    public class Request : IService<Request>.IRequest { }

    public void Do(Request request) { }
}
```

Comment: How can the last assertion be OK if request2 is not a derived type of the Request type, specified in the implementation of the Do method in Service class?

Comment: @jangix Look at my edit.

Comment: I don't understand from what you deduced that I had this misunderstanding. I questioned your fourth assertion because as I said Request2 is not a derivative of the Request type, as required by the type specified by the first parameter of the Do method implementation in the Service class (defined by me). Thank you anyway for your time spent for me.

Comment: @jangix The fourth assertion would be fine because I used **some** (not necessarily yours) implementation of the `IService`. Also please check my second edit. :-)

Comment: Your solution is valid, even I would have solved the problem with a generic IService. I opened this question not for a comparison of auric style but to understand the reasons for the error obtained in the specific case described initially.

Comment: @jangix Sorry, I misunderstood your intentions. So again: please read the first sentence at the very top of my reply. This is the direct reason why you received such an error. Nothing will change that. The logic behind why the compiler is so demanding has already been explained to you by MathiasR.Jessen, canton7 and me.

Comment: "inheritance of visibility" is a good reason to nest the definition of objects... as well as respecting the DDD

Comment: Your explanation and that of @canton7 are not enough for me, perhaps it is the example that does not highlight the practical problem well. From my point of view it's all legitimate... but thanks all the same

Comment: @jangix It is really not clear what you're after, in that case. "Not enough for me" is not something which is answerable. This answer clearly explains your mistake, and so answers "Why is this implementation incorrect?", which is the question in your OP. It therefore, IMO, answers your question, and should be accepted.